# -I dir search for gcc and clang

Tags: gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

When I use `-I` option with `gcc/clang`, does the preprocessor do a recursive downward search or just a search of a given directory? I found [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation) but it doesn't give a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

You found one part of the GNU Preprocesor manual.  You should also read the section on [Header files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/cpp/Header-Files.html#Header-Files).  It should say, somewhat more definitively, roughly what I say below.  For GNU's preprocessor, if it says otherwise, it is right.  What I say may still apply to other preprocessors (or it could be my mistake, but I hope not).

**TL;DR** — *there is no recursive search by the preprocessor.*

When the preprocessor sees:

```
#include <path/to/header.h>
#include "path/to/other.h"
```

then it tries to open the header file by adding the name in the `#include` line to various directory names that it has built-in or specified on the command line.  For headers enclosed in quote, it usually starts in the current directory (more precisely, the directory containing the current file), then looks in user-specified directories and finally system directories.  For headers enclosed in angle brackets, it usually omits the current directory.

Thus, if the compiler looks in `/usr/include` and the command line has `-I /opt/package/include`, then the compiler will probably try:

```
/opt/package/include/path/to/header.h
/usr/include/path/to/header.h

./path/to/other.h
/opt/package/include/path/to/other.h
/usr/include/path/to/other.h
```

If the header isn't found in one of those locations, you will get an error.

The terms 'usually' and 'probably' are there because the behaviour is implementation defined.  The searched locations could be the same for angle brackets and quotes.

If the `#include` directive appears inside another header, the compiler may use subtly different rules to find the nested included header.

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.10.2 Source file inclusion

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include <h-char-sequence> new-line
> ```
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by
>   the specified sequence between the `<` and `>` delimiters, and causes the replacement of that
>   directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header
>   identified is implementation-defined.
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include "q-char-sequence" new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the " delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> ```
> # include <h-char-sequence> new-line
> ```
>
> with the identical contained sequence (including `>` characters, if any) from the original directive.